# Affine 2D mapping in python

Tags: python, data-analysis, linear-algebra

I have two sets of 2D data $A$ and $B$ (representing 2D positions on a 2D plane $x,y$) which are related (the first pair of $x,y$ of $A$ is related to the first pair of $x,y$ of $B$ for instance). I want to map them using a 2x2 matrix $M$ and a vector $c$ such as:

$$B = M \cdot A + c + e$$

With $e$ being the gaussian error (mean of $0$ and variance of $\sigma^2$).

I want to find the matrix $M$ and vector $c$ for which the sum of squared distances between x,y coordinates is minimized.

How can I do that in python in the most efficient way ? I don't know much about Python and I feel kinda lost.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2):

Bias term $c$ can be eliminated (eg by subtracting the averages from $A$ and $B$) and the approximation be framed as:

$$B = M \cdot A$$

Using minimum sum of squared residual errors criterion (similar to MSE) the best approximation (and the matrix $M$) is given by [Least Squares method](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least_squares).

Using a python package like `numpy`, the least squares solution can be implemented relatively easily. Some packages like `scipy` have implemented it already.

**NB** If it is known that the matrix $M$ is fixed and constant (and not an approximation) then one can [identify the transformation matrix](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1929638/how-to-find-the-transformation-matrix-given-two-vectors-and-their-particular-tra) $M$ (and translation $c$) given only up to 3 points and their transformations. (`scipy` implements this as well if I am not mistaken).

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your answer. I tried to implement it using numpy and scipy. I tried also to stick to a strict implementation of my original post with M and c both present and distinct (I have to do it for later purpose).

Even if I do get a low sum of squared distances at the end (0.07), the result is not quite good if I plot it on a graph.

Here is my implementation and the data that I am using:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import minimize
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

A = np.array([
    [0, -6],
    [0, 6],
    [-6, 0],
    [6, 0],
    [-3, -3],
    [-3, 3],
    [0,0],
    [2, -2],
    [2, 4],
    [-3, 0],
    [-5, -3],
    [2, 5]
])

B = np.array([
    [0.45070423, 0.52288732],
    [0.125, 0.5625],
    [0.1754386, 0.15789474],
    [0.200489, 0.55012225],
    [0.30769231, 0.32451923],
    [0.1375, 0.45],
    [0.19935691, 0.46302251],
    [0.32142857, 0.53571429],
    [0.12765957, 0.53191489],
    [0.15246637, 0.30269058],
    [0.2247191, 0.20224719],
    [0.14379085, 0.55882353],
])

# MAPPING : getting M and c

def error_function(params):
    # Unpack M and c from the flat parameter array
    M = params[:4].reshape(2, 2)
    c = params[4:]
    
    predicted_B = (A @ M) + c

    # Calculate the sum of squared distances
    return np.sum(np.sum((predicted_B - B) ** 2, axis=1))

# Perform the optimization
initial_guess = np.zeros(6)
result = minimize(error_function, initial_guess)
M = result.x[:4].reshape(2, 2)
c = result.x[4:]

# Getting predictions
predicted_B = (A @ M) + c

# Plotting
plt.scatter(B[:,0], B[:,1], color='red', s=5)
plt.scatter(predicted_B[:,0], predicted_B[:,1], color='blue', s=5)
plt.show()
```

Did I implement it correctly ? I am not 100% sure about the minimization of the sum of squared distances.

I guess that the low sum of squared distances that I get is not that low since my targeted data are small values (between 0 and 0.7).

How could I improve it ?